# Grep behaves differently on Travis compared to locally

Tags: bash, grep, travis-ci

I've inherited a build script that checks for Copyright statements in our Travis build by getting a list of files that have changed and making sure they have a Copyright statement on them with the current year in it.  The part of the script that gets the years out is using grep to extract the years as follows:

```
GOSRCFILES=($(git diff --name-only origin/master | grep -v vendor | grep '\.go$'))
for GOFILE in "${GOSRCFILES[@]}"; do
  if grep -q "(C) Copyright" $GOFILE; then
      YEAR_LINE=$(grep -m 1 "(C) Copyright" $GOFILE)
      echo "Year line in ${GOFILE} is '${YEAR_LINE}'"
      YEARS=($(echo $YEAR_LINE | grep -oE '\d{4}'))
      echo "Years is ${YEARS[@]}"
  fi
done
```

This is working fine locally (on a Mac) but when it is run on Travis it fails.  The output locally is:

```
Year line in main.go is ' * (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2017, 2018 All Rights Reserved.'
Years is 2017 2018
```

Whereas on Travis it prints:

```
Year line in main.go is ' * (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2017, 2018 All Rights Reserved.'
Years is
```

As you can see it is finding the Copyright line OK but the command that extracts the `YEARS` (`YEARS=($(echo $YEAR_LINE | grep -oE '\d{4}'))`) from it is failing.  I've read through the man page for grep and can't see why it would behave differently for this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape `\d` is a Perl extension which is not usually supported in `grep` without additional options.  Use `[0-9]` or the POSIX class `[[:digit:]]` instead. (Understand the subtle differences; POSIX is locale-dependent, but on Travis, the locale is probably something undramatic.)

Tangentially, if you only use the array once, don't use an array; and you can avoid doing the first `grep` twice; and don't use uppercase for your private variables; and quote your variables; and print your diagnostics to standard error.

```
for gofile in $(git diff --name-only origin/master | grep -v vendor | grep '\.go$'); do
  if year_line=$(grep -m 1 "(C) Copyright" "$gofile"); then
    echo "Year line in $gofile is '$year_line'" >&2
    years=($(echo "$year_line" | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]{4}'))
    echo "Years is ${years[@]}" >&2
  fi
done
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot @tripleee and for the extra tips around writing bash scripts!